# How to print out and load all variables's names and values in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two simple functions as below. When I call the sim_train(), I expect the names and the values should be calculated avg_mean and avg_variance. However, the output is like this----all values are 0, although when I print out directly avg_mean and avg_variance and the values are correct.

```
SSS/avg_mean:0 [ 0.]
SSS/avg_variance:0 [ 0.]
-2.5 1.25
```

When I call sim_test(), it also shows

```
SSS/avg_mean:0 [ 0.]
SSS/avg_variance:0 [ 0.]
```

Is there any way for me to use the correct values in sim_test()? Thank you

```
def sim_train():
  x = tf.constant([-1,-2,-3,-4], tf.float32)
  with tf.variable_scope("SSS"):
    avg_mean = tf.get_variable(
        'avg_mean', [1], tf.float32,
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    avg_variance = tf.get_variable(
        'avg_variance', [1], tf.float32,
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))

    avg_mean, avg_variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  allVars = tf.global_variables()
  values = sess.run(allVars)

  for var, val in zip(allVars, values):
    print(var.name, val)

  print(avg_mean.eval(), avg_variance.eval())

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.save(sess, "/tmp/test_EMA/sim_save.ckpt")

def sim_test():
  #saver = tf.train.Saver()
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/test_EMA/sim_save.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/test_EMA/sim_save.ckpt")
  allVars = tf.global_variables()
  values = sess.run(allVars)
  for var, val in zip(allVars, values):
    print(var.name, val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not doing what you think is doing.

If you do

```
avg_mean = tf.get_variable(
    'avg_mean', [1], tf.float32,
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
print type(avg_mean)
```

the response will be

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'>
```

but if you do

```
avg_mean, avg_variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')
type(avg_mean)
```

the response will be

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

So the saver will go through and save your **Variable** successfully initialized to 0

To really assign the output of the moments function to the variable you need to use the assign op

for example:

```
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')
assign_op = avg_mean.assign([mean])
```

then in your session, you need to call `sess.run(assign_op)` and the value will be successfully stored to the Variable. 
Now Saver can save the value and you can restore it for later use.

Comment: Thank you @Kochoba. Your explanation is very clear and now my code works.

Comment: @Brandon If you found my answer helpful could you please upvote it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, Kochoba. Sorry that I can only accept the answer. Although I already upvote, but it will not show in public, because my id's reputation is low according to the notice...